# Retrieve Location Information only from GPS Sensor in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-manifest, android-gps, xamarin.essentials

Is there anyway I can configure my android app to take the location information only from GPS sensor. I am using **Xamarin.Essentials** package for getting the location information. And in my manifest I have added the following permissions based on the documentation.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

Can anyone please let me know which all permission / use-feature is not required for implementing the above request?

I tried different combinations of this but not sure which is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve Location Information only from GPS Sensor in Xamarin Android.
You should use Android native API to achieve it. If you used `Xamarin.Essentials` it will get the coordinates  by GPS Provider, Network Provider, Passive Provider.

Here is running GIF.
[image]

Add this permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And create a LocationManager instance like this:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
```

And then implement `LocationListener` and get coordinates by GPS:

```
   MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
   locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

MyLocationListener code.

```
       public class MyLocationListener : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
{

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyLocationListener(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }


    public void OnLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(
          mainActivity,
          "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.Latitude + " Lng: "
              + loc.Longitude, ToastLength.Short).Show();


    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the end, do not forget to request runtime permission.